# check i date is in dates array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I search a good way to check if one date is present into one array.
I'm able to chech if a string is in to an array but I can't modify the cose to use it with date.

```
    Dim datatest as date
    Dim arfest As Variant
    UR = Sheets("Fest").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    arfest = Sheets("Fest").Range("A2:A" & UR) 'A2=1/1/2015,A3=5/2/2015,A4=8/5/2015,.....
    datatest= 5/2/2015
    if instr(1, datatest, arfest,1) then ..
```

result: Error run-time '13', type not corresponding
what wrong?!?!

Answer (score 1):

3 points here:

1. When you read worksheet cells into a variant, if you don't specify the property (ie `Text`, `Value` or `Value2`), the default is `.Value`. This is always a bit risky with dates as you can't be sure about date formats. I find it easier to work with Excel's date values (which are `Long` and therefore not susceptible to formatting problems). You might therefore be better off specifying `.Value2`.
2. The variant array needs to be interrogated in a loop, ie checking each element of the array. So your `Instr` function won't work, as this checks a `String`.
3. If you decide to compare date values instead of the strings or dates themselves, the use `DateValue()` to convert a date to its Excel value and `CDate` to convert the value to a date.

You might consider rewriting your code as follows:

```
Dim datetest As Long
Dim arfest As Variant
Dim UR As Range
Dim i As Long

' Read the values into the variant array
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Fest")
    Set UR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)
    arfest = .Range("A1", UR).Value2
End With

datetest = DateValue(DateSerial(Year:=2015, Month:=2, Day:=5))

'Loop through the array, checking each date value
For i = 1 To UBound(arfest, 1)
    If arfest(i, 1) = datetest Then
        MsgBox DateValue(CDate(arfest(i, 1)))
    End If
Next
```

Comment: I saw now your post, thank .
you use arfest = .Range("A1", UR).Value2, but if I loop my array (symple arfest = .Range("A1", UR) the result is the value, I test it.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed  way with a loop, if I find the date into array, I add one day..

```
For Each i In arfest 
    If datatest = i Then datatest= DateAdd("d", 1, datatest)
Next i
```

forgive the hasty ask